# Java Click Counter using MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm trying to write a really simple Java example to learn MVC. It's a JButton that when clicked increments a counter and displays the number of clicks so far.

I broke out the Model, View and Controller into separate classes, and thought I was on the right path, but when I click the button the JLabel that displays the counter continues to stay at 0.

Can someone take a quick look and see why the JLabel that should display the number of clicks always stays at 0?

Thanks

```
View

package mvc;  
import javax.swing.JButton;  
import javax.swing.JLabel;  
import javax.swing.JTextArea;  
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;  
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;  


public class View extends javax.swing.JFrame {  
    private JButton jButton1;  
    private JLabel jLabel1;  
    private Controller c;   
    private Model m;  

    /**
    * Auto-generated main method to display this JFrame
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Controller c = new Controller();    

                Model m = new Model();

                View inst = new View(c,m);
                inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                inst.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public View(Controller c, Model m) {
        super();
        this.c = c;     
        this.m = m;
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().setLayout(null);
            {
                jButton1 = new JButton();
                getContentPane().add(jButton1, "Center");
                jButton1.setText("Click");
                jButton1.setBounds(314, 180, 101, 34);
                jButton1.addActionListener(c);
            }
            {
                jLabel1 = new JLabel();
                getContentPane().add(getJLabel1());
                jLabel1.setText("Click Count = " + c.getClickCount());
                jLabel1.setBounds(439, 183, 91, 27);

            }
            pack();
            this.setSize(818, 414);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //add your error handling code here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public JLabel getJLabel1() {
        return jLabel1;
    }   
}

End View

Controller class

package mvc;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Controller implements ActionListener 
{   
    Model m;
    View v;

    public Controller()
    {
        m = new Model();        
        v = new View(this, m);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        if (arg0.getSource() == "Click")
        {
            m.addClick();
            v.getJLabel1().setText("Click count = " + getClickCount());
        }

    }

    public int getClickCount()
    {
        return m.getClicks();
    }
}

End Controller class

Model class

package mvc;

public class Model 
{
    private int clicks;

    public Model()
    {
        clicks = 0;
    }

    public void addClick()
    {
        clicks++;
    }

    public int getClicks()
    {
        return clicks;
    }
}

End Model class
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems:

- The actual data should that view displays generally comes from the model not from the controller.

  So your code in the view 
  `jLabel1.setText("Click Count = " + c.getClickCount());`
  should change to 
  `jLabel1.setText("Click Count = " + m.getClickCount());`
- Inside the Controller, you create a new instance of the mode and view and inside the main() method you again create new instance of controller and view. So essentially the Controller class is working on a different view and model objects.

In general, but its not a stone-graved standard:

- The View has a model, it doesent refer to the controller
- The model is independent and doesent refer to view or controller
- The controller has both view and model.

Comment: Hi there, I removed the Model from the main() method and the View constructor now takes just a Controller as parameter.

Comment: Usually,The view takes a model. The model doesent take anything. The Controller takes both model and view. So the Model doesent know about the View and the Controller. The View only knows and uses the Model, not the Controller. The Controller can refer to both Model and View

Answer (score 0):

```
if (arg0.getSource() == "Click")
```

`==` is not meant for string (or object) equality comparison. `equals` method is what you should use instead.

Moreover, I think you are interested in [`public String getActionCommand()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand%28%29) method rather than [`public Object getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29).

A little test

```
JButton btn = new JButton();
btn.setText("Click");       
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getSource());
        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
    }
});
btn.doClick();
```

and the output

```
javax.swing.JButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@1f5b0afd,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=Click,defaultCapable=true]
Click
```

should illustrate why.

**Update**

Try

```
if (arg0.getActionCommand().equals("Click"))
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how to update my code, but I removed the "if (arg0.getSource() == "Click")" part since I only have 1 button. Still doesn't seem to update my click counter.

Comment: @user1729409: Updated my answer. Can you give it a try?

Comment: @user1729409: I think there are more problems, let me see if I can find.

Answer (score 0):

I see why now. You have two different Model objects created. 
One in controller and one in Main() - Which one is it?

Another advice.. create a MainController class. 
This should have your Main method. 
Your main method creates another Controller responsible for creating your View and Model. 
Use this Controller as the bridge.

Comment: So I ended up getting this to work. I now have the View with instance variables for the Model and Controller. The Controller takes a Model and View as arguments for its constructor. The Model doesn't know anything about the Controller or View. I created a MainController class to create and run the View class.

Thanks a bunch to everyone who helped!!

Answer (score 0):

The number always stays at zero because you are updating the wrong instance of `View`. In your `Controller` class you create another instance which is not displayed.

```
v = new View(this, m);
```

You could instead pass in your main instance by adding a setter:

```
class Controller implements ActionListener {
    Model m;
    View v;

    public Controller() {
        m = new Model();
    }

    public void setView(View v) {
        this.v = v;
    }
    ...
```

`ActionEvent.getSource()` returns a component reference but `jButton1` is not publicly visible. To fix you can either add a getter for the button or use the action command:

```
if (arg0.getActionCommand().equals("Click")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you could maybe try to make accessor to your button on the view class:

public JButton getButton(){

return jbutton1;

}

public void setButton(JButton button){

this.jbutton1 = button ;

}

and in your controler class accessing to your button like this:

if(arg0.getSource() == v.getButton()){

...

}

I always did like that and i never had any error...